# How to clean Google Chrome data except Extensions?

Tags: bash, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a script on MacOS which is cleaning a specific user files and folders from previous session each time that user logs in. It also cleaning Google Chrome Default folder located in /Users/user/Application Support/Google/Chrome path, logged in Google accounts in Chrome and browser history wipes out as well. Recently we added a custom Chrome extension so obviously script deleting it too.

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep ONLY extension. Since I'm answering only for a script, I'm not the one who developed the extension so I do not know the details on how the extensions are developed and what files and folders are related to them.

I tried to add this command in my script:

```
find /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default -mindepth 1 ! \( -name 'Extensions' -o -name 'Extension\ State' -o -name 'Local\ Extension\ Settings' \) -exec rm -rf {} +
```

And yes it's not working. System keeps those folders but extension removes from the browser.

The priority is to keep extension and remove all logged in Google accounts, browser history and cookie files.

Maybe there is other files or folders which are related to extensions so I should keep them as well?